# Change a value during edit in JTable

Tags: java, swing

```
JTable.setValueAt(Object obj, int row, int column);
```

won't work during edit of JTable. I found a way by which i can observe the table is edited or not.

```
if ("tableCellEditor".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
    if (table.isEditing()) {
        String value = table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 2).toString();
        if(value.equals("0")){
            System.out.println(value);
            table.setValueAt("", table.getSelectedRow(), 2);
        }
   }
}
```

This give me value 0 in output. But Set value do nothing...Basically i want to remove 0 during edit in this cell.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `CellEditorListener.editingStopped(ChangeEvent e)` and to invoke `table.setValueAt("", table.getSelectedRow(), 2);` from within that method?

Comment: cant understand. elaborate please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start to edit a cell the table get the data from the table model and displays it in the editor. So changing the table model won't affect the editor.

What you want to do is get the editor and change the value in the editor. The code might be something like:

```
JTextField editor = table.getEditorComponent();
editor.setText(...);
```

Comment: Without you Swing will almost dead. Everywhere i find you for swing base solution.